# Error in SQL only in RELEASE mode

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I'm fight with a strange error occurs a couple of day ago and I'm not able to find a solution.
I have a C# Form application that talks with a SQL database made by Visual Studio Express (.mdf file). Everything works fine if my connection string points to the database in the root directory (where the DB has been automatically created by VS). I can compile the executable in Debug and Release.

To do a test in a different machine (where I copied the executable file and the database .mdf)I have changed the connection string in order to point to the database in the same executable directory and, in this case, it doesn't work (both release and debug).

I come to my PC and I use the same connection string above pointing not to the DB in the root directory bu to DB in Release directory.

The strange thing is that it works in debug but not in release.

The error occurs is the following one

> Exception: One or more files do not match the primary file of the
>   database. If you are attempting to attach a database, retry the
>   operation with the correct files.  If this is an existing database,
>   the file may be corrupted and should be restored from a backup. Could
>   not open new database 'C:\USERS\TEST\VISUAL
>   STUDIO\PROJECTS\LEONARDO\LEONARDO
>   0.1.1.1\LEONARDO\BIN\RELEASE\DB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Test\Visual
>   Studio\Projects\Leonardo\Leonardo 0.1.1.1\Leonardo\bin\Release\DB.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share. Log file
>   'C:\Users\Test\Visual Studio\Projects\Leonardo\Leonardo
>   0.1.1.1\Leonardo\bin\Release\DB.ldf' does not match the primary file.  It may be from a different database or the log may have been rebuilt
>   previously.

and the code is

```
string Result = string.Empty;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.DataBasePath);

            try
            {

                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string Errore = String.Format("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);

                MessageBox.Show(Errore);

                throw;
            }

            SqlDataReader leggi = null;

            //SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + "Database Version" + " FROM Data", conn);
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Data", conn);

            leggi = comando.ExecuteReader();


            while (leggi.Read())
            {
                Result += leggi["Database Version"].ToString().TrimEnd();
            }

            conn.Close();
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
Log file 'C:\Users\Test\Visual Studio\Projects\Leonardo\Leonardo 0.1.1.1\Leonardo\bin\Release\DB.ldf' does not match the primary file.
```

You should make sure your debug and release folders contain the same .mdf and .ldf files.